# DropDown -- Truncate DateTime to Date in Oracle SQL or ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, oracle

Currently, I'm populating a DropDown with the following SQL:

```
SELECT REPORT_DATE FROM MY_TABLE
```

Although the values stored in the table are in the following format, `dd-mon-yyyy` (my preferred format), the text that fills my DropDown differs in that it also displays time, like `dd-mon-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM`.

What is the best way to resolve this?  I know of `TRUNC` and `TO_DATE` functions in Oracle SQL.  But I think I could also loop through the DropDown after its populated and truncate the string there.  I have tried the following code, but it returns a runtime error:

```
For Each i As ListItem In DropDown1.Items
        'Strip time here
        i.Text.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    Next
```

Essentially, I just want to loop my DropDown and change ONLY the text to match `dd-MMM-yyyy'.  How can I accomplish this? Should I use SQL or VB.NET?  Is there a best practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is of type DateTime, you can simply specify the DataTextFormatString property on the dropdown as so:

```
<asp:dropdownlist DataTextFormatString ="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" ... />
```

It should be to the UI layer to display the date in the format you want. You should try to avoid putting the logic to transform the date to the format you want on the SQL statement, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this sql side with

```
SELECT to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy') report_date FROM MY_TABLE order by report_date;
```

p.s.
"values stored in the table are in the following format, dd-mon-yyyy". dates are not stored like that, they are stored as an 7 byte numeric internally, how you see them on select is entirely dependant on your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting.

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering if Oracle was keeping the full DateTime internally and just displaying the Date when I viewed it in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this string to get data from Oracle

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(REPORT_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
i.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(i.Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

You cannot use `.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")` for date formatting on string. You need to convert it to DateTime

You can also try `<asp:DropDownList DataTextFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />`

Answer (score 1):

It's better to format the date in the DropDownList instead of letting sql doing it.

Just add DataTextFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" to your DropDownList tag :

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="adddate" 
        DataTextFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" DataValueField="adddate">
</asp:DropDownList>
```